# Detect tetrahedra within a triangulated mesh?

Tags: algorithm, math, 3d, geometry, mesh

Let's say I have a mesh that has lines connecting the vertices in a way that would allow it to be split into tetrahedra.  Is there an algorithm I can use to detect the presence of the tetrahedra given the vertices and lines?  (I.e., given the mesh with connecting lines, output a set of tetrahedra that have the same shape and volume.)

Edit: Tetrahedra are not allowed to intersect.

Comment: So are you saying that all of the edges necessary to form the tetrahedra are already present as the set of lines??

Comment: Yes, the edges are already present.

Comment: In what form do you have the vertices and edges?

Comment: There is an array for vertices [x, y] and an array for lines [index of start point in verticies array, index of end point in verticies array].

Comment: the vertices are [x,y,z] right? we cannot talk about a tetrahedra in 2D.

Comment: Sorry, you are correct, [x, y, z]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a graph-based approach may work.

First, the list of triangular faces can be recovered by noting that the set of edges define an undirected graph `G1(V1,E1)` for connectivity between the geometric vertices. A triangular face is any length 3 cycle in this graph.

```
for (i = all vertices in G1)
// form list of vertex triplets
    list = find all length 3 cycles from ith vertex
// push new faces onto output
    for (j = all triplets in list)
        [v1,v2,v3] = list(j)
        if ([v1,v2,v3] is not an existing face)
            push triplet [v1,v2,v3] as a new face
        endif
    endfor
endfor
```

Next, the tetrahedra can be recovered by forming the undirected graph `G2(V2,E2)` defining the connectivity between faces (i.e. faces are connected if they share an edge). A tetrahedra is any length 4 cycle in this graph.

```
for (i = all vertices in G2)
// form a list of face tuples
    list = find all length 4 cycles from ith vertex
// push new tetrahedra onto output
    for (j = all tuples in list)
        [f1,f2,f3] = list(j)
        [v1,v2,v3,v4] = unique vertices in faces [f1,f2,f3]
        if ([v1,v2,v3,v4] is not an existing tetrahedra)
            push tuple [v1,v2,v3,v4] as a new tetrahedra
        endif
    endif
endfor
```

Hope this helps.